# Redirecting input from cron job

Tags: cron, io-redirection

I'm using a plugin manager for vim (vim-plug), and have a cron job to perform updates:

```
vim +PlugUpgrade +qall &>/dev/null; vim +PlugUpdate +qall &>/dev/null
```

This job occasionally produces output like this:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

which gets sent to my mail. Does anyone know why it's generating this output despite redirecting to /dev/null (and how to stop it)?

Comment: AFAIK `&>` is a "bashism" - are you sure `cron` uses the `bash` shell on your system?

Comment: That's probably it, thanks - I mistakenly assumed it'd use my user's default shell.